# How to convert an existing HTML/JQuery to ASP.net/JQuery code

Tags: c#, jquery, html, asp.net, webforms

I have the following HTML page which displays some tabs along with contents and changes the content visiblity based on the tab clicked by the user:

HTML:

```
<ul id="tabs">
    <li><a href="#" title="tab1">One</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" title="tab2">Two</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" title="tab3">Three</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" title="tab4">Four</a></li>    
</ul>

<div id="content"> 
    <div id="tab1">THIS IS TAB 1</div>
    <div id="tab2">THIS IS TAB 2</div>
    <div id="tab3">THIS IS TAB 3</div>
    <div id="tab4">THIS IS TAB 4</div>
</div>
```

JQuery that hides and shows the the `content`:

```
<script> 
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#content div").hide(); // Initially hide all content
    $("#tabs li:first").attr("id","current"); // Activate first tab
    $("#content div:first").fadeIn(); // Show first tab content

    $('#tabs a').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();        
        $("#content div").hide(); //Hide all content
        $("#tabs li").attr("id",""); //Reset id's
        $(this).parent().attr("id","current"); // Activate this
        $('#' + $(this).attr('title')).fadeIn(); // Show content for current tab
    });
})();
</script>
```

Instead of `UL/LI` and `DIV`, I ended up using `<asp:BulletedList>` for `UL/LI` and `<asp:Panel>` for `DIV` because I will have to show and hide the tab from code behind.

So I created the following using ASP.net controls:

```
<asp:BulletedList ID="tabs" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" DisplayMode="HyperLink">
    <asp:ListItem Text="Status" Value="#"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="Your Tasks" Value="#"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="Messages" Value="#"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="Dependencies" Value="#"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="Documents" Value="#"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="Pro-Forma" Value="#"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="Admin Controls" Value="#"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:BulletedList>

<asp:Panel ID="content" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static">
    <asp:Panel ID="tab1" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server">THIS IS A TEST #1</asp:Panel>
    <asp:Panel ID="tab2" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server">THIS IS A TEST #2</asp:Panel>
    <asp:Panel ID="tab3" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server">THIS IS A TEST #3</asp:Panel>
    <asp:Panel ID="tab4" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server">THIS IS A TEST #4</asp:Panel>
    <asp:Panel ID="tab5" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server">THIS IS A TEST #5</asp:Panel>
    <asp:Panel ID="tab6" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server">THIS IS A TEST #6</asp:Panel>
    <asp:Panel ID="tab7" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server">THIS IS A TEST #7</asp:Panel>
</asp:Panel>
```

and kept the same JQuery as posted before. When I load the ASP.net page for the first time, `Status` tab is highlighted and `tab1` from the `content` panel is displayed. When I click on any of the tab the `content` panel just doesn't show anything, it's blank.

I realized, it's because the JQuery is using the `title` tag from the link inside each `LI`, but unfortunately I can't use `HyperLink` inside the `<asp:ListItem>` because VS complains saying it's not a standard. How can I modify my code so I am able to use the ASP.net controls and have the JQuery working correctly?

Chrome shows this:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your HTML in the beginning with this, putting the tab target in the href:

```
<asp:BulletedList ID="tabs" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" DisplayMode="HyperLink">
    <asp:ListItem Text="Status" Value="#tab1"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="Your Tasks" Value="#tab2"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="Messages" Value="#tab3"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="Dependencies" Value="#tab4"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="Documents" Value="#tab5"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="Pro-Forma" Value="#tab6"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="Admin Controls" Value="#tab7"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:BulletedList>
```

Then change the last line in your jQuery from:

```
$('#' + $(this).attr('title')).fadeIn(); // Show content for current tab
```

To:

```
$($(this).attr('href')).fadeIn();
```

Revise your script block to chain animations on the fadeIn for the active tab as well, like so:

```
// Initially hide all content
$("#content div").css('display', 'none');

// Then activate the first tab
$("#tabs li:first").attr("id", "current");

// Now fade it in
$("#content div:first").fadeIn();

// Click event 
$('#tabs a').click(function (e) {

    // Get a handle to the current object when we move into the scope 
    // of the hide callback
    var what = $(this);

    e.preventDefault();

    // Hide all content
    $("#content div:visible").hide(
        0,
        function () {
            $("#tabs li").attr("id", ""); //Reset id's
            what.parent().attr("id", "current"); // Activate this
            $(what.attr('href')).fadeIn();
        }
    ); 

    // Return false to ensure navigation doesn't fire
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Thanks!!! :) Works great in IE from VS but when I copy the URL of the site into Chrome all the contents div are being shown... I will update my question with the screenshot.

Comment: Well I don't care much for I.E. so I'd rather have a Mozilla / webKit friendly solution.  I tested this in Firefox, I'll check it out in Chrome.

Comment: I'm not doubting you, but it worked for me in Windows Chrome 35 the same as it did in Firefox 30.

Comment: Have you looked at the screenshot? Chome is not showing correctly... I don't care about IE either ;) but unfortunately the end-user will be using IE primarily.

Comment: The current tab isn't highlighted and all the DIV shows up when page loads in Chrome and FF :/

Comment: This was my original question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24808627/why-jquery-isnt-executing-inside-a-contentplaceholder. The hover over nor the tab script is working correctly for me.

Comment: Maybe because Chrome and FF doesn't work until I have deployed my solution first?

Comment: Hard to say without seeing the rest of your HTML.  Any script errors?

Comment: I was told by my SharePoint admin, the package needs to be displayed so the JQuery will kick in... Thank you.

Comment: Do you need anything further?  And if not can you mark the answer acknowledged?

Comment: Thank you. SO didn't allow me to so I was waiting :)

Answer (score 0):

Found this answer here: http://channel9.msdn.com/Forums/TechOff/257894-aspnet-BulletedList-list-item-with-HTML-

Try using a Repeater. The BulletedList unfortunately doesn't support HTML for its ListItems.

Markup

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server">
    <HeaderTemplate><ul></HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate><li><span class="label">Test</span> <%# Container.DataItem %></li></ItemTemplate>
    <FooterTemplate></ul></FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Comment: Actually it is rendering as HTML UL/LI but I want the <a> inside to have the Title.